# Jmeter vs apache benchmark to test a solr-nutch application?

Tags: jmeter, nutch, apachebench, solr8

what is more convenient to use Jmeter or Apache benchmark as a load test for my system without crashing the system. which is easier and simple to use?
I just need to know the average or maximum number of requests for the system.
I'm using solar8.3.1 and nutch1.16.

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions regarding solr and nutch testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is a web-crawler and [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is a search platform my expectation is that you will be testing the performance of Solrs [JSON Request API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/json-request-api.html)

**ab** will be "easier and simple to use" if you want just to hammer the Solr API endpoint with a fixed number of concurrent requests.

**JMeter** will be more convenient to use because it looks like you're about to perform a [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing), to wit start with 1 virtual user and [ramping-up the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/) until response time starts exceeding acceptable or errors start occurring. Moreover [JMeter has better reporting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: In this case how can I use ab? 
Thank you

Comment: Stress test wont crush my system?

Comment: Refer to the documentation for "How can I use ab?": https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html
And YES - of course you can crush your system ... If you do it manually: Closely monitor your test and stop it as soon as something unexpected occurs (usually errors and/or timeouts). If you have some sort of test concept available or in the planning: that´s where your exit criteria should kick in.

Comment: I don't think that test will "crush" your system, however it might stop responding or nutch/solr will be terminated by i.e. [OOMKiller](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-oom-killer.html). With JMeter you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) allowing monitoring baseline OS health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.) as well as Solr JMX metrics. With regards to `ab` - see i.e. [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_bench/index.htm)